# Toggle enable and disable all Buttons with one Button

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to disable all my Buttons by using another Button's Click event, then re-enable them again if I click that Button again.

I tried this code but it failed:

```vb
 Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click 
    If Button3.Enabled = True Then
        Button1.Enabled = False
        Button6.Enabled = False
        Button7.Enabled = False
        Button2.Enabled = False
        Button9.Enabled = False
    ElseIf Button3.Enabled = True Then
        Button1.Enabled = True
        Button6.Enabled = True
        Button7.Enabled = True
        Button2.Enabled = True
        Button9.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Well both If/ElseIf statements check for Button3.Enabled = true so only the first will ever trigger.

Comment: You should clarify the condition that enables/disables your Buttons. Is it the `.Enabled` status of Button3 or you just want to toggle the `.Enabled` status of all the Buttons in that list on an event (another Button click, for example)? The `End Sub` in your code is the end of what `Sub`?

Comment: Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

Comment: how to clarify my condition? can you re-structured my code pls? thanks

Comment: and yes i want to toggle my button again and again disabled and enables all of my buttons

Comment: i just want to toggle my button3.click to enable and disable. how can i do that?

Comment: You can update your question any time, using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54412506/edit) link.

Comment: i already edit thanks!

Comment: If button3 is disabled, you won't be able to click it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click    

'use button1 or button6 or button 7 or button2 or button9 for the condition not the button 3 because it is the button that will trigger for enabling and disabling
        If Button1.Enabled = True Then
                    Button1.Enabled = False
                    Button6.Enabled = False
                    Button7.Enabled = False
                    Button2.Enabled = False
                    Button9.Enabled = False

                'in the elseif statement use the disabled buttons like button1 or button6 or button 7 or button2 or button9 for your condition to detect if it is disabled so that it will change its state from being disabled to enable
          ElseIf Button1.Enabled = false Then
                    Button1.Enabled = True
                    Button6.Enabled = True
                    Button7.Enabled = True
                    Button2.Enabled = True
                    Button9.Enabled = True

                End If
    End Sub
```

Here is my modification:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        If Button5.Enabled = True Then
            Button5.Enabled = False
            Button6.Enabled = False
            Button7.Enabled = False
            Button8.Enabled = False
            Button9.Enabled = False
        ElseIf Button5.Enabled = False Then
            Button5.Enabled = True
            Button6.Enabled = True
            Button7.Enabled = True
            Button8.Enabled = True
            Button9.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

[View image here for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkXFg.jpg)

Comment: please explain further what you really want to happen?
Do you mean, when you press the button3 if the 5 buttons are disabled it will enabled and if the 5 buttons are enabled if you press the button3 again it will disabled?
Is that what you realy want to happen?

Comment: try the code above, i have modified it, i just follow the way you really want to happen i think....

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to accomplish this.
For example, you could keep a collection of the indexes of the Buttons that you want to toggle and, on a `Button.Click` event, use a `for each` loop to change their **`Enabled`** status:

> Note that this code supposes that your Buttons are placed on a Form.
>   It they're inside another Container (e.g., a Panel), use that
>   Container's name instead of the **`Me`** reference.

```vb
Private toggleButtons As Integer() = {1, 2, 6, 7, 9}

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click    
    For Each idx As Integer In toggleButtons
        Me.Controls("Button" & idx.ToString).Enabled = Not Me.Controls("Button" & idx.ToString).Enabled
    Next
End Sub
```

Much alike the previous example, pre-selecting the Buttons that need to toggle:

```vb
Private toggleButtons As Button()

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    toggleButtons = New Button() {Button1, Button2, Button6, Button7, Button9}
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click    
    For Each btn As Button In toggleButtons
        btn.Enabled = Not btn.Enabled
    Next
End Sub
```

You could also set the `Tag` property of those Buttons to some specific value, then use this property value to tell them apart.

For example, setting the `Tag` property of the Buttons you want to toggle to `"toggleButton"`:

```vb
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click    
    For Each btn As Button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)
        If btn.Tag IsNot Nothing AndAlso btn.Tag.ToString().Equals("ToggleButton") Then
            btn.Enabled = Not btn.Enabled
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Or specialized class that knows its Buttons and how/when to toggle them.
Or implement a specific Interface (...)

Comment: i dont get it sir sorry, im still weak with this. can you give me the simplest code so that i can understand? thanks

Comment: I made some modifications. Try the first example, see whether it's understandable enough.

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'  this is the error that ive got

Comment: What reference was not set? The `toggleButtons` array shown in th first code snippet, maybe? One of the Buttons? If you tell me where/when the error is generated, I can help you fix it.